# add json string escape characters

Tags: json, swift

```
let params = [["_event": "bulk-subscribe", "tzID":8, "message":"pid-1175152:"]]
let jParams = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
var jsonString:String = String.init(data: jParams, encoding: .utf8) ?? "err"
```

The result of the code is to get the following values

> [{"_event":"bulk-subscribe","tzID":8,"message":"pid-1175152:"}]

The result I want is the following values. Result value with " added

> ["{"_event":"bulk-subscribe","tzID":8,"message":"pid-1175152:"}"]

What do I need to fix?
Thank you

Comment: You mean `["{\"_event\":\"bulk-subscribe\",\"tzID\":8,\"message\":\"pid-1175152:\"}"]` right? Else it's not valid JSON.

Comment: If that's the case: `let topJSON = [jsonString]; let topJParams = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: topJSON, options: []); let debugOutput = String.init(data: topJParams, encoding: .utf8)`

Comment: Doesn’t make any sense what you are trying to achieve. Why do you need to convert your json dictionary into a string inside the array?

Comment: Post your actual problem. Your “solution” it is probably not what you need.

Comment: @LeoDabus not common Some websocket protocols are strange

Comment: Is it always just a single string? Again it doesn't make any sense. Anyway if that is really what you need just encode the resulting jsonStringArray of vadian post. `let data = JSONENcoder().emcode(jsonStringArray)`

Answer (score 1):

Your requested output is an array containing one element, a serialized JSON **dictionary**.

You get this by creating `params` as a dictionary

```
let params : [String:Any] = ["_event": "bulk-subscribe", "tzID":8, "message":"pid-1175152:"]
```

and wrap the result of the serialization in square brackets. There are no *escape characters* involved.

```
let jParams = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params)
let jsonStringArray = [String(data: jParams, encoding: .utf8)!]
```